# sqlite make variable from subquery count

Tags: sqlite, count, subquery

I have two tables in a sqlite database like:

```
CREATE TABLE list (
    list_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    title TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE item (
    item_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    title TEXT NOT NULL,
    completed INTEGER NOT NULL,
    list_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES list (list_id)
);
```

I want to perform a query on the list table that returns the id, title and creates a variable `completed` that is `true` or 1 if all of the `item` rows that reference it are completed otherwise `false` or `0`.

I am quite new to sql (so not sure if this is even possible) but this is just a bit beyond me at the moment. Any help or pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `completed` on the `item` table is a 1 or 0.

```
SELECT  L.LIST_ID
        ,L.TITLE
        ,MAX(I.COMPLETED)
FROM    LIST L
LEFT OUTER JOIN
        ITEM I
ON      I.LIST_ID = L.LIST_ID
GROUP BY
        L.LIST_ID
        ,L.TITLE
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I changed the `MAX` to `MIN` as I wanted the column to return `0` if there was at least one item not completed, other than that it worked a charm.